# How to store files in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-blob-storage

We need to store ~50k files every year. Each file is 0.1-5mb which translates to 5gb - 250gb range. Files are: jpg, avi, pdf, docx,etc.

We used to just store file BLOBs in sql server but I guess it's not the best idea in this scenario because database will be huge in 2 years.

What would be the best way to store that data?

I see a lot of different options there and cannot figure out where to start:
Azure storage, Azure SQL, etc. There's also some hybrid versions in new versions of SQL server.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following approach for multiple systems.

- Azure Storage for files. You can create multiple containers and access levels if storing proprietary information.
- Azure CDN for serving static content from Azure Storage
- Azure DB as a database engine

In Azure DB I store the path the the file, with some additional processing in my applications for how to access the file to build up the final URL to serve the file from. This is due to CDN lacking SSL support on custom domains.

If you need examples or more info, just let me know. I'm sitting at an airport so providing a slightly less detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! We currently use SQL Server. Does it mean that we will need to move to Azure DB if we choose to use suggested setup?

Comment: Not at all. Azure DB is just a cheaper option, but you can store the data of where the file is location in SQL Server (local or cloud) and use Azure storage for file.s

Comment: Okay. so, does it mean that we get hard link to the file like: mywebsite.com/files/image.jpg?

Comment: Also, do you know if there's an option to run images/video through a compression so those files have smaller size?

Comment: I store something like "files/image.jpg" in the database along the container to look for. I then have some code that builds the final url of "http://mycdnurl.com/container/files.image.jpg" when I access it. This allows me to access same named files (graphics, etc) for development off a different endpoint so I can see that they work before going live.

Comment: There are options for video and image compression. Look at the Azure streaming service for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin! Let me play with it and see if this is what we need.

Answer (score 5):

As @Martin mentioned in his answer, Azure Storage is viable, specifically because:

- Access is independent of any VM, service, database, etc.
- Storage is *durable* - triple-replicated within a region, and optionally geo-replicated
- Individual blobs may be up to 200GB, with storage scaling to 500TB

Azure also provides File Service, which is essentially an SMB share sitting on top of blobs.

While there are database services in Azure (SQL Database Service and DocumentDB), you'll find that these are not really optimized for large binary data storage; they're more optimized for metadata. You can certainly store binary data in each of them, but you'll need to worry about storage limits.

You may also spin up your own database solution via Virtual Machines, along with attached disks (again, backed by durable blob storage). Virtual Machines support up to 32 1TB disks attached to a given VM, whether normal blobs or "premium" SSD-based blobs (each premium disk supporting up to 5000 IOPS). *Which* database solution you choose is completely up to you; there is no "best" solution.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on my answer with more information. :)

Comment: We don't really need anything like super-durable high-availability. Just something that is going to be cost-effective. Currently we host our website on Azure with SQL server Entity Framework code first.

Comment: I guess we will try Azure storage and see if it works for us. Thank you David!

Comment: @user194076 - there is no "super-durable" - it's either durable or it's not. And if it's not (e.g. you store it in your local scratch storage), it's gone the moment your machine reboots or gets reprovisioned.